# Webpack 2: How to exclude all node_modules except for

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I need to have babel run on `/node_modules/identicons/` However I still want to exclude all other packages.

Reason is **[the identicons package](https://github.com/blog/1586-identicons)** is using template strings and breaks when I run

`"webpack -p"`

String in question (node_modules/identicons/index.js):

```
str += `<rect x="${x}" y="${y}" width="${xside}" height="${xside}" style="fill:${color}" />`
```

### Webpack.config.babel

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      //include: /node_modules/identicons/,
      use: ["babel-loader"]
    },
```

How would that pattern be written?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can use regex, something like

```
exclude: [
  /node_modules\/(?!identicons).*/
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
exclude: [
  {
    test: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/MODULE_TO_INCLUDE'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/ANOTHER_MODULE_TO_INCLUDE'),
    ]
  }
]
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could exclude everything from `node_modules` that is not `identicons`:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!identicons$)/
```

Answer (score 3):

Exclude whole `node_modules` folder, except required module:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!identicons\/).*/,
}
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-219040479