# Webpack 4x how to exclude multiple node_modules directories

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a project with multiple node_modules directories

```
myproj
   |-->app1
     package.json
     |-->node_modules
     |-->src

   |-->origapp_reactnative
     package.json
     |-->node_modules
     |-->shared_src

   |-->app2
     package.json
     |-->node_modules
     |-->src
```

When bulding app1 or app2 with webpack (from their respecitive root dirs.).
I must specify

```
   resolve.modules=[path.resolve(__dirname,"./node_modules")]
```

If I do not do that, then webpack will try to pull code from

```
   |-->origapp_reactnative
     |-->node_modules
```

Because app1 or app2 include sources from shared_src.
And webpack tries to follow nodejs convention and look for node_modules in the dir next to shared_src.

So that's why I am setting resolve.modules to an absolute path.

However, that creates another problem, that I cannot overcome:
webpack flattens the dependency tree within node_modules specified by absolute path. And that creates dependency problem, where modules of different versions cannot coexist.

So I am looking for a way to use, therefore, relative path

```
   resolve.modules=["./node_modules"]
```

But need help to figure out how to exclude the node_modules

```
   |-->origapp_reactnative
     |-->node_modules
```

from webpacks consideration.

(
I have tried to instruct babel loader  as discussed here [1], not to look there -- but that's not enough, because compilation still will fails.
)

[1] [Webpack 2: How to exclude all node_modules except for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246365/webpack-2-how-to-exclude-all-node-modules-except-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be almost there. When you build `app1` and only want to use `node_modules` from `app1`, you can use [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) with a relative path `app1/node_modules`.

#### Solution with `resolve.modules`

webpack config in `app1`:

```
const path = require("path");
...

module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js"],
    modules: [path.basename(__dirname) + "/node_modules"]
  },
};
```

(Assumptions: `cwd` pointed to `app1`'s root, webpack config in `app1`'s root)

With `path.basename`, you can make your config more independent from the actual project name, effectively having the setting `modules: ["app1/node_modules"]`. If you import something from `shared_src`, which on his part uses `node_modules`, it will traverse via node resolution up to `myproj` and from there find the path `app1/node_modules`.

You could also add `node_modules` as [fallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules), if you have additional packages only installed in the shared project:

```
// first entry takes precedence.
modules: [path.basename(__dirname) + "/node_modules", "node_modules"]
```

[`resolveLoader`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveloader) can be set as extra property for loaders, if you happen to get an error not being able to find loaders from `node_modules` afterwards.

#### Alternative: `resolve.alias`

If all you need is importing a few packages from a specific node_modules folder,
you could also use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) (for example resolve `react` here from `./node_modules`):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react")
  }
}
```

#### Note about babel-loader

> ( I have tried to instruct babel loader as discussed here [1](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules), not to look there -- but that's not enough, because compilation still will fails. )

Babel-loader and Co. use the absolute file path that is already [resolved](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) for [rule conditions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions), if you want to exclude something to be transformed. In every case `exclude` and other filter options of loaders do not prevent your imported modules (like the ones in `node_modules`) from being excluded. When modules are filtered out, it only means, they aren't further processed by Babel loader (or other loaders, where you have defined rule conditions).

Hope, that helps.